# Recursive JSON Parser

Tags: android, json

I need to parse this json through recursion..

```
{
    "code": "200",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "BE",
            "parent": "0",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "name": "Computer Science",
                    "parent": "2",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "4",
                            "name": "1st Year",
                            "parent": "3",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "id": "8",
                                    "name": "A",
                                    "parent": "4",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "9",
                                    "name": "B",
                                    "parent": "4",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "5",
                            "name": "2nd Year",
                            "parent": "3",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "id": "10",
                                    "name": "A",
                                    "parent": "5",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "11",
                                    "name": "B",
                                    "parent": "5",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "6",
                            "name": "3rd Year",
                            "parent": "3",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "id": "12",
                                    "name": "A",
                                    "parent": "6",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "13",
                                    "name": "B",
                                    "parent": "6",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "7",
                            "name": "4th Year",
                            "parent": "3",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "id": "14",
                                    "name": "A",
                                    "parent": "7",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "15",
                                    "name": "B",
                                    "parent": "7",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "16",
            "name": "ME",
            "parent": "0",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "17",
            "name": "Btech",
            "parent": "0",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: I need to parse this and want to set to a spinners.. after selecting BE/ME/Btech i need to get the child data [computer science in second spinner] after selecting computer science again need to get the child data like 1st yr or 2nd yr in seperate spinner

Comment: All JSON parsers will recursively parse through the tree. Just navigate through the java.util.Map based on the selected key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but logically it should work this way:

```
public void solve(JSONArray dataArray){
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject dataObj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println(dataObj.getString("id"));
            System.out.println(dataObj.getString("name"));
            System.out.println(dataObj.getString("parent"));
            JSONArray childArray = dataObj.getJSONArray("children");
            solve(childArray);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
    {
        JSONObject json=new JSONObject("response");
        JSONArray dataArray = json.getJSONArray("data");
        for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject dataObj=dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println(dataObj.getString("id"));
            System.out.println(dataObj.getString("name"));
            System.out.println(dataObj.getString("parent"));
            JSONArray childArray=dataObj.getJSONArray("children");
            for(int j=0;j<childArray.length();j++)
            {
                JSONObject childObj=childArray.getJSONObject(j);
                System.out.println(childObj.getString("id"));
                System.out.println(childObj.getString("name"));
                System.out.println(childObj.getString("parent"));
            }

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```